# Writing output from a Hadoop combiner

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

In Hadoop 2.2.0, I have several values that can be output by a combiner, instead of sending them to a reducer.

I tried MultipleOutputs to output to a specific file from the combiner. Sadly, I get an exception when multiple combiners are created for one mapper, as they try to access the same file.

Is there any way to create different partitions for each combiner?

Simplified code:

```
    public class Combiner1 extends Reducer {

        String FILENAME = "tmp_round1_comb.txt";

        protected MultipleOutputs mos;

        @Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            super.setup(context);

            String s = String.format("Combiner-%05d-%d",
                    context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID().getId(),
                    context.getTaskAttemptID().getId());
            LOG.info(s);

            mos = new MultipleOutputs(context);

        }


        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            if (specialCase) {
                ...
                mos.write(out1, out2, FILENAME);

            } else {
                ....
                context.write(key, out);

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            mos.close();
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
     2014-10-13 14:53:00,045 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
      2014-10-13 14:53:00,045 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask: Ignoring exception during close for org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector@61f2bf35
      java.io.IOException: Spill failed
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.checkSpillException(MapTask.java:1535)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1444)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.close(MapTask.java:700)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.closeQuietly(MapTask.java:1990)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:774)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
      Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: failed to create file /user/cloudera/scratch/Profiling_q4/20141013_145034/tmp/TMP_0_Out1/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1412109710756_0057_m_000000_0/tmp_round1_comb.txt-m-00000 on client 127.0.0.1 because the file exists
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2307)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2235)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2188)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:505)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:354)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)

      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1603)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1461)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1386)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:394)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.getRecordWriter(MultipleOutputs.java:475)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.write(MultipleOutputs.java:457)
      at mapreduce.guardedfragment.executor.hadoop.combiners.GFCombiner1.reduce(GFCombiner1.java:139)
      at mapreduce.guardedfragment.executor.hadoop.combiners.GFCombiner1.reduce(GFCombiner1.java:31)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1645)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1611)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.access$900(MapTask.java:853)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$SpillThread.run(MapTask.java:1505)
      Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException): failed to create file /user/cloudera/scratch/Profiling_q4/20141013_145034/tmp/TMP_0_Out1/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1412109710756_0057_m_000000_0/tmp_round1_comb.txt-m-00000 on client 127.0.0.1 because the file exists
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2307)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2235)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2188)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:505)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:354)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)

      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1409)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1362)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:258)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1599)
      ... 20 more
      2014-10-13 14:53:00,048 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.IOException: Spill failed
      2014-10-13 14:53:00,049 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.io.IOException: Spill failed
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.checkSpillException(MapTask.java:1535)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.access$300(MapTask.java:853)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$Buffer.write(MapTask.java:1349)
      at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.write(Text.java:324)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:98)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableSerializer.serialize(WritableSerialization.java:82)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1126)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:692)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112)
      at mapreduce.guardedfragment.executor.hadoop.mappers.GFMapper1Guard.map(GFMapper1Guard.java:98)
      at mapreduce.guardedfragment.executor.hadoop.mappers.GFMapper1Guard.map(GFMapper1Guard.java:37)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.DelegatingMapper.run(DelegatingMapper.java:55)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:340)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
      Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: failed to create file /user/cloudera/scratch/Profiling_q4/20141013_145034/tmp/TMP_0_Out1/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1412109710756_0057_m_000000_0/tmp_round1_comb.txt-m-00000 on client 127.0.0.1 because the file exists
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2307)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2235)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2188)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:505)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:354)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)

      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1603)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1461)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1386)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:394)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:390)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:334)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:784)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:132)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.getRecordWriter(MultipleOutputs.java:475)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.write(MultipleOutputs.java:457)
      at mapreduce.guardedfragment.executor.hadoop.combiners.GFCombiner1.reduce(GFCombiner1.java:139)
      at mapreduce.guardedfragment.executor.hadoop.combiners.GFCombiner1.reduce(GFCombiner1.java:31)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:171)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$NewCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1645)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1611)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.access$900(MapTask.java:853)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer$SpillThread.run(MapTask.java:1505)
      Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException): failed to create file /user/cloudera/scratch/Profiling_q4/20141013_145034/tmp/TMP_0_Out1/_temporary/1/_temporary/attempt_1412109710756_0057_m_000000_0/tmp_round1_comb.txt-m-00000 on client 127.0.0.1 because the file exists
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2307)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2235)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2188)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:505)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:354)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1986)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1982)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
      at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1980)

      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1409)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1362)
      at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:186)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.create(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:258)
      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1599)
      ... 20 more

      2014-10

-13 14:53:00,065 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task: Runnning cleanup for the task
```

Comment: you may add the stackTrace and code as well.